# The simplest way to display Strings with icons in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

What is please **the easiest** way to show a list of Strings and icons in a `RecyclerView`?

For `ListView` I use the following code (here [a full project at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/Planets)) **without** a separate Adapter:

[image: app screenshot]

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        mPlanets) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_stars_black_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
            return view;
    }
});
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view,
                                int position,
                                long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You have clicked " + mPlanets[position],
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

I wonder how to use `ArrayAdapter` and `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` with [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) in a similarly simple way, that is without custom layouts and adapters.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Buddy this is the most simplest way

1. first add the dependency in **build.gradle** file

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
   ```
2. In your MainActivity define RecyclerView Object

   ```
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
   private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
   private ArrayList<String> planetList=new ArrayList();
   //Other Stuff

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //Other Stuff and initialize planetList with all the planets name before passing it to adapter

       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
       layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

       adapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList,getApplicationContext());
       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```
3. The Main Buzz Killer **PlanetAdapter**,You have to define PlanetAdapter which extends  RecyclerView.Adapter

   ```
   public class PlanetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder> {

       ArrayList<String> planetList;

       public PlanetAdapter(ArrayList<String> planetList, Context context) {
           this.planetList = planetList;
       }

       @Override
       public PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.planet_row,parent,false);
           PlanetViewHolder viewHolder=new PlanetViewHolder(v);
           return viewHolder;
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder holder, int position) {
           holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.planetimage);
           holder.text.setText(planetList.get(position).toString());
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return planetList.size();
       }

       public static class PlanetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

           protected ImageView image;
           protected TextView text;

           public PlanetViewHolder(View itemView) {
               super(itemView);
               image= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
               text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

4.main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

5. The last But not the least planet_row.xml

   ```
   <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="40dp"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:id="@+id/image_id"/>

        <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Planet Name"
             android:id="@+id/text_id"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21` is out of date. Use `22.2.1`.

Comment: OMG Its just like tomorrow I learnt it and today it got out of date :D sure in Programming world nothing is static

Comment: where is onclick funcionallity ?

Comment: inside onBindViewHolder() function you can do something like this 'holder.text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do something
            }
        });'

Comment: do you still need a custom layout if we use simple_list_item_1 in the inflate?

Answer (score 11):

I have reduced L-X's solution (thanks!) by few lines in my [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/Planets/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/planets/MainActivity.java):

First a `ViewHolder` class with click listener:

```
private class PlanetViewHolder
        extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    public PlanetViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // also possible: v.getContext()
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You have clicked " + ((TextView) v).getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And then the adapter overriding 3 abstract methods and using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`:

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter<PlanetViewHolder>() {

        @Override
        public PlanetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    parent,
                    false);
            PlanetViewHolder vh = new PlanetViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PlanetViewHolder vh, int position) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) vh.itemView;
            tv.setText(mPlanets[position]);
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_stars_black_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mPlanets.length;
        }
    });
```

The above code displays array of String `mPlanets` as:

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: I like it .. its simple and short . I would add that if anyone would like to have position index inside onClick .. just use getAdapterPosition()